# How to use a reference without year in new ACM template?

Tags: bibtex, acm

I'm using the new 2017 [ACM standard template](http://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template). In the bibliography I want to refer to a website without the year and want to format it like so

> [1] Title of website, URL

However, the template seems to produce `(????)` unless I specify a year. Using "n.d." (not dated) instead of the year is not what I want.

Maybe there is a particular publication type that allows that? `@misc` and `@online` do not seem to help.

I looked at the source code of the corresponding [ACM-Reference-Format.bst](http://www.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/acmart/current/ACM-Reference-Format.bst) and the function "format.year" seems to enforce that a year is mandatory, but maybe there is a way around that?

Comment: I've stumbled across the same issue. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: I have the same issue...any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

ACM thinks that a year is too important to omit.  You may  write it as `2012(?)` or `[2012]` for estimated or not stated year, but it must be there.