# How to get rid of (n.d) from misc entries without date in Sigconf, ACM-Reference-Format?

Tags: bibliographies, acm, acmart

I am trying to get rid of the `(n.d)` that appears in the citations.

Below is my MWP.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@misc{google,
  title={Google},
  howpublished={\url{https://google.com}},
  author={Google}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

Something to cite~\cite{google}.

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{ref.bib}

\end{document}
```

I tried to include the following code, for example, from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336089/106952) answer just before `\begin{document}`. However, I get **Undefined control sequence** error for `\DeclareLabeldate` and `\field`.

```
\DeclareLabeldate[online]{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \field{urldate}
}
```

This [discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355772/how-to-use-a-reference-without-year-in-new-acm-template) hints that it may require something more to be tweaked?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use biblatex. The file [`ACM-Reference-Format.bbx`](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/blob/fd887a614829bb91b4b02e382394fd26d2641736/ACM-Reference-Format.bbx#L71) defines the following macro:

```
\newbibmacro*{year}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}%
    {\printtext{[n.\ d.]}}%
    {\printfield{year}}%
}
```

Fortunately, we can redefine this macro using `renewbibmacro` in the following way:

```
\renewbibmacro*{year}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}%
    {}% We omitted the default value "[n. d.]" of ACM here!
    {\printfield{year}}%
}
```

As a result, the following biblatex record:

```
@online{speedtest1,
  title = {{SQLite}, speedtest1},
  url   = {https://sqlite.org/cpu.html}
}
```

Renders without the date:

[image: biblatex reference without the default value when the date is omitted]